# Cost Basis Of Stocks Of Numbers of Companies With A Financial Firm Before Transfer To The Present and Of Records Lost To Client?

Tags: taxes, stock-exchanges, cost-basis

What if there are shares of companies each which were purchased six to nineteen years ago with a prior financial firm before being transferred to the present financial firm? What are ways to get the cost basis for these stocks?

How does one handle a sale of these shares if the basis isn't known?

Comment: How much information do you have about the stock purchases? Year and month? Date?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of options to consider:

- If you can at least narrow down to the year, you can choose the "worst case" which is to use the lowest value during that year. In an audit, you'd still need to explain how you chose the year.
- Claim zero. Over 20 years, the S&P is up 6 fold. If the shares are worth $20,000, and your cost was say, $4000, a claim of zero costs you $600 more than if you had the $4000 figure. This is a last resort, I am just showing the numbers for this decision. Since you don't mention the amount, it could be anything.
- If the current value is in the range of a few year's charitable donations (e.g. the stocks are worth $5000 today and you happen to donate say $2000 a year) consider donating the shares to a charitable fund. Schwab and Fidelity both offer such funds. You take the deduction now for the current stock value. You then direct then to make donations in whatever value you choose until he money is used up.

I hope others might add another idea here. The ideal choice really depends on the actual numbers involved. The charitable donation is the cleanest option if it works for you. For those who are charitable, this is actually better than donating cash as the benefit is increased by the money you don't pay on the cap gain.

Comment: If even a few quarterly statements are available Option 1 can still be made to work. Just pick the lowest point between the statements.

Comment: Good point, any statements showing no stock in month A, but there in month B will narrow it down.